# Excel 2010: How can I change formulas across multiple cells without modifying their input values?

Tags: excel

I would like to bulk-change formulas across multiple cells without altering the input value. Is there a way to make this change without going cell by cell, or creating a macro to go cell by cell, and manually replacing the formula type?

When I say input values, I mean the contents of the parenthesis, following a given formula; which, in this case, is the "(number, significance)" values which are specific to each cell.

For example:

I have a column of cells which contain something like the following,

- In D40, we have =ROUNDUP(197.3+14.84+109.09+12.18+12.18, 5);
- In D47, we have =MROUND(85.16+40+24+47+24+19+9+8, 5);
- And so on, for an entire column with hundreds of cells

I want to change every function within those cells to =CEILING without changing the inputs, so that

- D40 would change to =CEILING(197.3+14.84+109.09+12.18+12.18, 5);
- D47 would change to =CEILING(85.16+40+24+47+24+19+9+8, 5);
- And so on for every cell

---

Specific Considerations:

- I am not familiar with macros, and I won't be surprised if there is no alternative means to automate the changes;
- I am using Excel 2010, MSFT Office Pro;
- The spreadsheet is a quantity takeoff, where all values within the parenthesis of each cell's formula are input manually and reflect different linear foot values from architectural plans;
- The group of cells I want to change are all contained in the same column;
- The CURRENT formula (the one I want to replace) is the same for every cell, and it is =ROUNDUP;
- The PROPOSED formula (the one I want to replace the current formula) is the same, and I want it to be =CEILING; and
- I REQUIRE that the contents of the parenthesis remain unchanged.

---

I've tried to make sure this is not a duplicate question, but my apologies if I just didn't find the original. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does the standard "Find and replace" function not work for you?

Comment: Ha! That is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do "Ctrl+f", then go to "Replace" tab. 
In textbox for "Find what:" write "ROUNDUP" and in textbox for "Replace with:" write "CEILING".
On last step, click "Replace All" button.