# Fix formula error via formula in Google sheet after xlsx import

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When importing an xlsx file into a Google sheet, I end up with a **formula parse error** because the cells of one column contain wrong date formulae like `==DATE(2021,3,12)`.
Obviously the problem is that there is one "=" to many.

I cannot go ahead and manually fix the error in every cell, so I would need some other formula to get rid of the of the additional "=" at the beginning of the cell content. I thought about using something like `=RIGHT()`, but this again results in an error, since the referenced cell already contains an error and cannot be interpreted as string.

In the end I would like to import the column containing the (wrongly formatted) dates into another spreadsheet via the `=IMPORTRANGE()` formula and at the same time get rid of the additional "=" at the beginning of the cell content.

If possible I would like to do this without the help of a script, but if it's only possible with one, then I am grateful for ideas here as well. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's doesn't make sense to use a formula to fix another formula as that it's very likely that will require too much effort compared with other options i.e. use find and replace to replace all `==DATE` by `=DATE`, just check the checkbox to search inside formulas. This could be done before or after importing to Google Sheets as Excel and Google Sheets have similar features for this.

Related

Excel

- [Excel 2010: How can I change formulas across multiple cells without modifying their input values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42060307/1595451)

Google Sheets

- [Search the formula content in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43305867/1595451)
- [Is it possible to mass edit formulas in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57295868/1595451)